# Не убирается класс у svg элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

Смотрите, я хочу чтобы при изменении ширины экрана у меню убирался класс actived, точнее у svg элемента. Но он не срабатывает. Всё убирается кроме actived класс. Подскажите ошибку.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $('body').innerWidth(),
      list = $(".menu-list");
    desc = $(".description");
    mbtn = $(".menu-toggle button svg");

    if (windowWidth > 991) {
      list.removeClass('show transf');
      desc.removeClass('desc-fix');
      mbtn.remove('actived');
    } else {}
  }

  checkWidth();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-toggle button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.hamRotate.actived {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamRotate180.actived {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}

.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}

.ham1.actived .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}

.ham1.actived .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggle text-right">
  <button id="menu-toggle">
    <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60" onclick="this.classList.toggle('actived')">
    <path class="line top"
    d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    <path class="line middle"
    d="m 30,50 h 40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    <path class="line bottom"
    d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
$('.menu-toggle button svg').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu-list').toggleClass('show transf');
  $('.description').toggleClass('desc-fix');
  $('.menu-toggle button svg').toggleClass('actived');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $('body').innerWidth(),
      list = $(".menu-list");
    desc = $(".description");
    mbtn = $(".menu-toggle button svg");

    if (windowWidth > 991) {
      list.removeClass('show transf');
      desc.removeClass('desc-fix');
      mbtn.removeClass('actived');
    } else {}
  }

  checkWidth();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: 23px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.menu ul li {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-family: "Europe", sans-serif;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.logo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo p {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Colus", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo p::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 4.5px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.search {
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}

.search input {
  width: 80%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 30px 1px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.search input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
  font-style: italic;
}

.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
  font-style: italic;
}

.search input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
  font-style: italic;
}

.search input::placeholder {
  color: #bcbcbc;
  font-style: italic;
}

.search button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 5.5%;
}

.description {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.description h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-toggle button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 400ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 400ms;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  transition: transform 400ms, -webkit-transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.hamRotate.actived {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamRotate180.actived {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}

.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}

.ham1.actived .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}

.ham1.actived .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}

.menu-list {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.menu-list ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu-list ul li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-list ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-list ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 d-md-none d-xl-block d-lg-block d-sm-none d-none">
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="page-proofs.html">
                                    test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contacts.html#contacts">
                                    test
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-4">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">
                                test
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-5">
                    <div class="search">
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск" required>
                            <button type="submit">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-lg-none d-xl-none col-md-2 col-sm-2 d-md-block col-3">
                    <div class="menu-toggle text-right">
                        <button id="menu-toggle">
                            <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60"
                                 onClick="this.classList.toggle('actived')">
                                <path class="line top"
                                      d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40"
                                      fill="#1a1a1a"/>
                                <path class="line middle"
                                      d="m 30,50 h 40" fill="#1a1a1a"/>
                                <path class="line bottom"
                                      d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40"
                                      fill="#1a1a1a"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="menu-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">
                test
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="page-proofs.html">
                test
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contacts.html#contacts">
                test
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: а почему просто на медиа запросах нельзя скрыть эту кнопку ?

Comment: это так и задумано, что для  `actived` удаляется весь элемент, а не только класс?

Comment: Смотри, это кнопка меню, actived - это когда она активная, то есть она изменилась в крестик и когда человек допустим перевернет устройство в стоянии actived оно не уйдёт, а меню скроется, а когда назад вернёт в положение до 991 будет активный крести, хотя должны быть 3 палочки. Вот мне и нужно когда больше 991 чтобы убирался крестик, а именно класс actived

Comment: но сейчас ты вызываешь `mbtn.remove('actived');`  а [`.remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) удаляет элемент, а не класс с элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в строке `mbtn.remove('actived');`.

В данном случае идет попытка удалить элемент `<actived>` из набора, в котором только `svg` элемент.

Если заменить этот код, на тот, который используется для остальных классов

```
mbtn.removeClass('actived');
```

Все начинает работать так, как и ожидалось.

В сниппете по кнопке развернуть можно увидеть, что условие отрабатывает, класс убирается, и крестик меняется на гамбургер

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $('body').innerWidth(),
      list = $(".menu-list");
    desc = $(".description");
    mbtn = $(".menu-toggle button svg");

    console.log('resize', windowWidth);
    if (windowWidth > 991) {
      list.removeClass('show transf');
      desc.removeClass('desc-fix');
      mbtn.removeClass('actived');
    } else {}
  }

  checkWidth();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-toggle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-toggle button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.hamRotate.actived {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamRotate180.actived {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}

.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}

.ham1.actived .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}

.ham1.actived .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggle text-right">
  <button id="menu-toggle">
    <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60" onclick="this.classList.toggle('actived')">
    <path class="line top"
    d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    <path class="line middle"
    d="m 30,50 h 40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    <path class="line bottom"
    d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" fill="#1a1a1a" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё тоже самое, не работает.

Comment: @w3cwhy, в сниппете не работает? После запуска сниппета нажатия на бургер и разворачивания на весь экран он остается крестиком?

Comment: Да, он скрывается, вместо него появляется меню, после когда я возвращаю в диапазон меньше 991px - крестик, а меню скрыто.

Comment: @w3cwhy, в моем сниппете нет никакого меню :-)

Comment: Наверно не кто не понял, что я хочу

Comment: @w3cwhy, код в сниппете выполняет ровно то, что ты описал: при изменении размера на больший 991 убирает класс actived у элемента. Если ты хотел не это, добавь в вопрос больше описания и примеров

Comment: Смотри суть в чём. Есть размер до 991, там есть меню, поиск и так далее. Как только меньше 991, оно уже не влезает и появляется меню бургер, но проблема в том что, если человек нажмёт на кнопку она станет крестиком и если в этом положении он переведёт экран в ширину больше 991 меню скроется и появится поиск и пункты меню, а когда вернёт назад - будет крести, а должны быть 3 палочки, вот и нужно сделать так чтобы если длина больше 991 отнимался класс actived. Чтобы когда человек перевернул экран - были 3 палочки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106271/discussion-between-grundy-and-w3cwhy).